# Read a string chay by char using interruptions

Tags: assembly, x86

so, I am implementing a function that reads a string letter by letter, and I can only read a certain amount of letters. I take the letter that is stored in letter ("letter resd 1") and I put it in the buffer ("buffer resd 100"). But when I print it, all I see is gibberish. This is the critical part of the code:

`mov dword [buffer + 4*esi], letter`

This is happening inside the function in a loop. The register "esi" starts with zero and is incremented every loop until it reaches 100. I am 100% positive that "letter" contains 1 letter that I read previusly by doing this:

```
    mov eax, 3
    mov ebx, 0
    mov ecx, letter
    mov edx, 1
    int 80h
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: A letter is 1 byte, not 4. Why are you scaling by 4? Also, `letter` is the address, not the value. You want something more like `mov al, [letter]; mov [buffer+esi], al`. Of course you could read into the buffer directly too.

Comment: @Jester thanks, that helps a lot, but my buffer always has whatever I typed multiplied by 2. Any idea why? If I type "qwerty" and then print the buffer, It has "qwertyqwerty". I was scalling by 4 for every 32 bit space in "buffer" has 1 letter, that's at least what I am trying to do.

Comment: It's unclear why you want 32 bits per letter, but if so, don't expect sensible output. Still should not print things twice, which sounds like you are getting to the print code twice. Hard to tell without a [mcve].